# Como criar um dicionário com uma palavra e sua adjacente a partir de uma string?

Tags: python

Tenho a seguinte *string*:

```
texto = "We are not what we should be We are not what we need to be But at least we are not what we used to be"
```

Este seria o retorno que eu queria: para cada palavra existente no texto, a mesma receber a palavra adjacente a ela.

Exemplo:

```
retorno = {‘we’: [‘are’, ‘should’, ‘are’, ‘need’, ‘are’, ‘used’], ‘are’: [‘not’, ‘not’]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para pegar cada palavra e sua adjacente, podemos dividir a *string* nos espaços em branco e utilizar a função `zip` para agrupá-las em pares:

```
texto = "We are not what we should be We are not what we need to be But at least we are not what we used to be"
palavras = texto.split()

for a, b in zip(palavras, palavras[1:]):
    ...
```

Como você quer gerar um dicionário de listas, podemos utilizar `collections.defaultdict` para simplificar:

```
from collections import defautdict

resultado = defaultdict(list)

texto = "We are not what we should be We are not what we need to be But at least we are not what we used to be"
palavras = texto.split()

for a, b in zip(palavras, palavras[1:]):
    resultado[a.lower()].append(b.lower())
```

Assim, `resultado` será a representação de:

```
{
    'we': ['are', 'should', 'are', 'need', 'are', 'used'], 
    'are': ['not', 'not', 'not'], 
    'not': ['what', 'what', 'what'], 
    'what': ['we', 'we', 'we'], 
    'should': ['be'], 
    'be': ['we', 'but'], 
    'need': ['to'], 
    'to': ['be', 'be'], 
    'but': ['at'], 
    'at': ['least'], 
    'least': ['we'], 
    'used': ['to']
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente você quebra a frase em palavras:

```
words = texto.lower().split()
```

Com essa lista de palavras, basta iterar em cima dela, anexando a próxima palavra. Para que não tenha muito trabalho, pode usar a funciona `collections.defaultdict`, que vai criar um dicionario de listas pra voce. O código ficaria assim:

```
import collections
adjacente = collections.defaultdict(list)

for (i, word) in enumerate(words[:-1]):
    next_word = words[i + 1]
    adjacente[word].append(next_word)
```

Lembrando que fazemos -1 para pegar n - 1 palavras, já que a ultima palavra não tem palavras adjacentes a ela.

E o resultado:

```
adjacente
defaultdict(list,
        {'But': ['at'],
         'We': ['are', 'are'],
         'are': ['not', 'not', 'not'],
         'at': ['least'],
         'be': ['We', 'But'],
         'least': ['we'],
         'need': ['to'],
         'not': ['what', 'what', 'what'],
         'should': ['be'],
         'to': ['be', 'be'],
         'used': ['to'],
         'we': ['should', 'need', 'are', 'used'],
         'what': ['we', 'we', 'we']})
```

Caso você queria que as palavras sejam únicas, troque no `defaultdict` de `list` para `set` e em vez de append, use update passando um vetor com a next_word.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui assim também.

```
texto = "We are not what we should be We are not what we need to be But at least we are not what we used to be"

lista = texto.lower().split()

dic = {}

for i in range(len(lista) - 1):
    current = lista[i]
    next_ = lista[i + 1]
    if current not in dic:
        dic[current] = []

    dic[current].append(next_)

print(dic)
```